# How to get publication metadata on DXA?

Tags: dxa

I'm implementing DXA(STRI, SDL Tridion Reference Implementation).
I need to define publication metadata, for instance locale ID or date format string,and get them in template(DXA view). I read documentation and search internet, but I couldn't find information about how to get publication metadata.

Is it possible to get publication metadata on DXA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a requirement to store these config values in your publication metadata ?
DXA has some built-in features for this. It allows you to store your settings in a key-value like configuration component.

You can read more about it here
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-216696B0-073F-4188-9584-6112CD15729B

Comment: correct and multiple configuration Components can be added so you can keep configurations in separate Components for easy management (and rights on each).